# Hosting basic html site on iis

Tags: html, iis

I have a basic web site (just html, js and css files) that I want to host on IIS on my local machine for testing purposes. The site runs fine when I run it directly as a file on my computer. I added a website on IIS, using the directory these files are located in, but when I try to launch it, I get an error page that says:

An error occurred loading a configuration file: Failed to start monitoring changes to '[my site path]' because access is denied.

It then says that the source file is a web.config. I know that ASP.NET sites use a web.config, but I don't even have one, and I just want to run a basic site using html, css, and javascript.

Any ideas on what the fix might be? I made sure I have an application pool for the site.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You likely put it into your user profile -- ie c:\users\skitterm\ -- which won't let the process running IIS read the folder. You are better off using IIS' built in directory structure in c:\inetpub and adding a folder for your site.

Answer (score 0):

As you can tell this is a server misconfiguration. It would help to know the version of your IIS.

You can follow the steps on Microsoft's official knowledgebase to resolve the issue:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316721

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317955 (for IIS v6.0, try Method 3)

I worked in IIS about a year ago and such errors are caused by misconfigured Security settings in IIS.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to set up the proper access rights for the folder to the account specified by the application pool identity.

First make sure that your folder is *not* anywhere under your `\users\`, `\program files\`, or any other place that already has restricted access. Put it under a folder on the root (`\inetpub` is a good place).

Then, add the appropriate permissions (usually read only) for the folder to allow the user account specified by the app pool identity to access it. If the app pool identity is set to ApplicationPoolIdentity, adding the IIS_IUSRS local group should do it. Otherwise, use the account that is specified.

This should fix the problem.