# How to publish Polymer 2/3 projects on IIS?

Tags: iis, visual-studio-2017, polymer

Is there any way to serve a polymer 2/3 project on IIS instead of webpack? I searched about it but I haven't found anything really useful for me.

Comment: By `2/3`, do you mean the version; like `2.3`?

Comment: By 2/3, I mean Polymer 2 or Polymer 3.

Comment: Webpack and IIS are two different concepts, they are a build/compression utility and a server respectively. Why not to create a deployable build of polymer project as mentioned [here](https://www.polymer-project.org/3.0/start/toolbox/deploy#build-for-deployment) and then follow [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24415053/hosting-basic-html-site-on-iis). Please elaborate the question revealing more about your code if I am missing something.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I will give a shot.

Comment: Why don't you want to use  `polymer serve` command on cmd for local hosting. :)